# c: Timer wont allow program to finish

Tags: c, timer

I have this simple encrypt/decrypt program and it works just fine. But our teacher asked us to time it, so I used the timer. My problem is, when I implement the timer, it won't end the program. It does reach the last brace when I debug it, but never exits the program. What is wrong? Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<alloc.h>

void encrypt(char *crypt,char *plaintext,char *encryption,int size)
{
    int i,j,k,flags;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        j=1;flags=0;
        while(j<53 && flags==0)
        {
            if(plaintext[i]==crypt[j])
            {
                encryption[i]=crypt[j-1];
                flags=1;
            }
            k=j+2;

            j=k;
        }
    }
}

void decrypt(char *crypt,char *ciphertext,char *decryption,int s)
{
    int m,i,j,k,flag;
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        j=0;flag=0;
        while(j<52 && flag==0)
        {
            if(ciphertext[i]==crypt[j])
            {
                decryption[i]=crypt[j+1];
                flag=1;
            }
            k=j+2;
            j=k;
        }
    }
}

main()
{
    char c,*from, *to;
    int size;
    char crypt[53]="afbicddeelftgyhbirjakvlnmgncohpjqkrmsotpuqvswuxwyxzz";
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;
    clrscr();
    printf("press e to encrypt and d to decrypt: ");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    if(c=='e')
    {
        scanf("%s",from);
        size=strlen(from);
        begin=clock();
        encrypt(crypt,from,to,size);
        end=clock();
        time_spent=(double)(end-begin)/CLK_TCK;
    }
    else
    {
        scanf("%s",from);
        size=strlen(from);
        begin=clock();
        decrypt(crypt,from,to,size);
        end=clock();
        time_spent=(double)(end-begin)/CLK_TCK;
    }
    printf("%s",to);
    printf  ("%e",time_spent);
    free(from); from=NULL;
    free(to); to=NULL;
}
```

I've tried removing the timer, and it works well again. But I really need the timer. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You `scanf` into `from` which is uninitialized - that's undefined behavior. You then write data to `to` which is unitialized - that's undefined behavior. Then you `free` both those pointers which are uninitialized and pointing to who-knows-what - that's uninitialized behavior.

Comment: I initialized it already. Still the same, the program does not end.

Comment: How did you initialize them? Also are you familiar with debuggers? If not, then maybe `printf`-style debugging would help you track the flow of your program.

Comment: I just set both to NULL before I put values into them.

Comment: I debugged it, that's why I know that the program reached to the last outer brace. It does everything in the program, it just does not terminate.

Comment: That's wrong - you are *writing* data into a `NULL` pointer (`from`) with the `scanf`. And then you read data via a `NULL` pointer and write data via a `NULL` pointer (`from` and `to` respectively). Try `char from[512], to[512]` instead; it's not a perfect solution, but it will work for now. And please, pick up a good book on C programming. This is elementary stuff.

Comment: ok but I swear the code works fine without the timer.

Comment: That's the problem with undefined behavior - it can appear to work. Things can be set up so you overwrite memory you shouldn't and things appear to be fine, and then you add one more thing in there, and it throws everything off.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths is correct. OP code without the timer routines hid the memory problem on OP's run.  The program may seemingly work fine without the timer today, but may fail tomorrow or an another machine or fail with another compiler.

Answer (score 0):

OP is scanning and writing into unknown memory, as @Nik Bougalis said, with

```
char *from, *to;
scanf("%s",from);
encrypt(crypt,from,to,size);
decrypt(crypt,from,to,size);
```

It sometimes appears to work and other times not as it is UB.
Suggest allocating memory.

```
char *from, *to;
from = malloc(1000);
to = malloc(1000);
// test if ((from == NULL) || (to == NULL)) here for serious code.
from[0] = '\0';
...
scanf(" %999[^\n]", from); // 2 places
```

Using `%[^\n]` vs. `%s` has the advantage that you may enter white-space (other than new-line) which is more apropos for this problem.

[edit] Added a `space` to " %999[^\n]" to consume the likely new-line left-over from the previous `scanf("%c",&c)`.